# -1 records Segmentation Fault core dumped

Tags: tcl, helper, ns2

I am trying to transmit a binary file (frame of a video frame) using Application/Traffic/Trace in NS-2, from node 1 to node 2, it gives me the error, Segmentation Fault Core dumped. The TCL script is given below:

```
set ns [new Simulator]

set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]
set n4 [$ns node]
set n5 [$ns node]


set f [open aj/star.tr w]
$ns trace-all $f
set nf [open aj/star.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf


$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1.5Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n2 10Mb 5ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n3 10Mb 5ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n4 10Mb 5ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n5 10Mb 5ms DropTail


set tfile [new Tracefile]
$tfile filename starwars

set original_file_name csencoding.binary
set trace_file_name video.dat
set original_file_id [open $original_file_name r]
set trace_file_id [open $trace_file_name wb]
set s4 [new Agent/UDP]
$ns attach-agent $n4 $s4

set null1 [new Agent/Null]
$ns attach-agent $n1 $null1

$ns connect $s4 $null1

set trace [new Application/Traffic/Trace]
$trace attach-tracefile $tfile

$trace attach-agent $s4



$ns at 1.0 "$trace start"

$ns at 110.0 "$trace stop"

$ns at 120.0 "finish"

proc finish {} {

         global ns nf f
         $ns flush-trace
         close $f
         close $nf
  exec nam aj/star.nam &
         exit 0

}

$ns run
```

Binary File:

1000110
1101111
1110010
1100101
1101101
1100001
1101110
1010001
1000011
1001001
1000110
0101110
0110000
0110000
0110000
0101110
1110000
1100111
1101101
1011111
1000011
1010011
1000100
1100001
1110100
1100001
0101110
1100100
1100001
1110100

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. The button is labelled `Ask Question` for a reason.

Comment: You may want to change your tag(s); `helper` really doesn't seem a useful tag here. `tcl` perhaps?

Comment: The binary data is the filename "ForemanQCIF.000.pgm_CSData.dat". I suspect that "set original_file_id [open $original_file_name r]" should open "ForemanQCIF.000.pgm_CSData.dat" instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Binary string to text

You need to get the filename as text or convert the csencoding.binary to text before trying to open the file.  It's failing to open the "1000110..." representation of the filename.  Here's a proc that can convert the 7 digit binary to text.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set bin "1000110 1101111 1110010 1100101 1101101 1100001 1101110 1010001 1000011 1001001 1000110 0101110 0110000 0110000 0110000 0101110 1110000 1100111 1101101 1011111 1000011 1010011 1000100 1100001 1110100 1100001 0101110 1100100 1100001 1110100"

proc bin7str {bin} {
        set str ""
        foreach {el} $bin {
                append str [binary format B* "0${el}"]
        }
        return $str
}

puts [bin7str $bin]
```

Output:

```
./bin.tcl
ForemanQCIF.000.pgm_CSData.dat
```

Comment: On second thought I don't see $original_file_id being used after opening the file. It looks like it's unused unless there is an upvar or upleveling to get at it.